# importScripts Call Stack Size Exceeded in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, amazon-ec2, web-worker, stack-size

When my webworker executes importScripts, it throws a RangeError in chrome; however, this is only seen in production on an ec2 instance. When running the application locally or deploying it to Heroku, the webworker is able to call importScripts with no trouble. Additionally, the ec2-deployed version of the app runs just fine in Safari.

Production EC2 - Chrome - Not Working
Production EC2 - Safari - Working
Production Heroku - Chrome - Working
Production Safari - Chrome - Working
Local Dev - Chrome - Working
Local Dev - Safari - Working

I attempted to start chrome with a larger stack size, but that didn't solve the issue. It's leading me to believe there is something wrong with the way that the app is serving assets, but this is only a hypothesis.

More details about the problem:

The dysfunctional part of the app is a ThreeJS model running the PhysiJS physics plugin. The Physijs worker calls importScripts on the path to ammo.js, which contains all of the functions for calculating velocity, collision, etc.

The app is built on Rails with Nginx and Puma and is running on a small ec2 instance. The physijs worker and the ammo file are precompiled.

If the instance is running, it's available at 52.27.230.200.

Chrome Logs:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: scene is not defined
>   THREE.WebGLRenderer 71
>   unhandled obj_info Array[3]
>   unhandled obj_info Array[3]
>   THREE.Geometry
>   THREE.Geometry
>   unhandled obj_info Array[3]
>   unhandled obj_info Array[3]
>   Uncaught Error: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setX' of undefined
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setIdentity' of undefined
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setX' of undefined
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setIdentity' of undefined
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setX' of undefined
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setIdentity' of undefined
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setX' of undefined
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setIdentity' of undefined
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setX' of undefined
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setIdentity' of undefined